# Why don't Phony pre-requisites appear in `$?`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, toolchain, unix-ar

Example: let's say I have a `bar.c` and `baz.c`, I want to produce `foo.a`. So:

```
foo.a: bar.o baz.o
    ar -rc $@ $?
```

Now I decide I *always* want `bar.o` to be updated. I decide to make it a Phony target. This also requires an explicit recipe for it, since implicit rules don't get searched for Phony targets. So:

```
.PHONY: bar.o
bar.o: bar.c
    cc -c -o $@ $<

foo.a: bar.o baz.o
    ar -rc $@ $?
```

Now when I run `make foo.a`, `bar.c` always gets compiled. Since `bar.o` gets updated, `foo.a`'s recipe always gets run.

**But**: `$?` has an empty value so `foo.a` doesn't get modified. Why?

Comment: Make obviously doesn't disallow this but the manual does say "A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file". Since phony targets are always executed it makes sense that they'd be considered always older than anything else internally.

Comment: @user657267 Always executed would map to newer more readily than older since a recipe *generally* updates its target when it runs. That said the "should not" is because a target that lists a phony prerequisite will, itself, always run because the phony target will be seen as newer.

Comment: @EtanReisner you're right, got my times confused. Perhaps internally phony files have a special date value that's neither newer nor older.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I'm not sure exactly but I suspect it is because phony targets are exactly that "phony" as-in they are explicitly expected **not** to represent files and so having them in the list of prerequisites newer than the target doesn't really make all that much sense.

That said if you want to keep this behavior but handle things correctly you want to *avoid* a `.PHONY` target and instead use a [forced target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets).

> If a rule has no prerequisites or recipe, and the target of the rule is a nonexistent file, then make imagines this target to have been updated whenever its rule is run. This implies that all targets depending on this one will always have their recipe run.
>
> An example will illustrate this:
>
> ```
> clean: FORCE
>     rm $(objects)
> FORCE:
> ```
>
> Here the target ‘FORCE’ satisfies the special conditions, so the target clean that depends on it is forced to run its recipe. There is nothing special about the name ‘FORCE’, but that is one name commonly used this way.
>
> As you can see, using ‘FORCE’ this way has the same results as using ‘.PHONY: clean’.
>
> Using ‘.PHONY’ is more explicit and more efficient. However, other versions of make do not support ‘.PHONY’; thus ‘FORCE’ appears in many makefiles. See Phony Targets.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's worth noting that Phony targets *do* appear in `$^`, which strikes me as inconsistent.

Comment: Yes and no. They *are* prerequisites but they aren't (in actuality) newer than the target. So it does make some sense but I agree it is a bit odd.